# Using BufferedReader to read a single line in Java

Tags: java, file, csv, bufferedreader

I have code successfully reading from a CSV. However when I try to use `fileReader` to read a solo line, it makes my code stop working.

Here is my code:

```
try {
    String line = "";
    fileReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filename));

    while ((line = fileReader.readLine()) != null) {
        String[] tokens = line.split(DELIMITER);
        for (String token : tokens) {
            totalData.add(token);
            if (!artists.contains(token)) {
                artists.add(token);
            }
        }
        for (int l = 0; l <= 999; l++) {
            lineData = fileReader.readLine();
            lineArray[l] = lineData;
        }

    }
} finally {
    fileReader.close();
}
```

When I try to read `arrayList` sizes and print data I get from the `arrayList`s above this code below makes it stop working:

```
for (int l = 0; l <= 80; l++) {
    lineData = fileReader.readLine();
    lineArray[l] = lineData;
}
```

If I comment this for loop, everything is fine. I really need this for loop, how can I edit my code to resolve this issue? Also, what is happening?

Comment: why do you do it? `lineData = fileReader.readLine();`

Comment: @AndrewTobilko I want to pull each of the lines separately so that I can do a `.contains()` on each line later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for (int l = 0; l <= 80; l++) {
    lineData = fileReader.readLine();
    lineArray[l] = lineData;
}
```

This hard code can replace a single line of code:

```
lineArray[i++] = line;
```

I corrected your code and that's what happened:

```
String line = "";
int i = 0;
try (BufferedReader fileReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(""))) {
    while ((line = fileReader.readLine()) != null) {
        lineArray[i++] = line;
        String[] tokens = line.split(DELIMITER);
        for (String token : tokens) {
            totalData.add(token);
            if (!artists.contains(token)) {
                artists.add(token);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It does fix is, but I don't understand why.

Comment: @Justin, you use `for` statement in the `while`.

Comment: @Justin , `while` statement helps you to read the lines: `while ((line = fileReader.readLine()) != null)`. You must not call  any `readLine()` methods in this statement.

Comment: @Justin, Do you understand? Don't afraid to ask.

Comment: I just understand it is conflicting I suppose.

Comment: Debug step by step your old code and you will know why